# NullPointerException while using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, static-methods, powermock

getting null pointer exception while mocking getTimeZone method. defaultSystemTimezone is populated from property file.

```
SummaryServiceTest.java: 

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Calendar.class, TimeZone.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class SummaryServiceTest{

    @Mock
    BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private SummaryService summaryService;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getBookingRejections() throws Exception {
        TimeZone timezoneObj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Cambridge_Bay");
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TimeZone.class);
        Mockito.when(TimeZone.getTimeZone(eq("America/Cambridge_Bay"))).thenReturn(timezoneObj);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.US);
        Calendar ac = PowerMockito.mock(Calendar.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(calendar1).when(ac , "getInstance");
        Boolean bookingRejectionsByWeekForCarrierList = summaryService.getBookingRejections();
    }
}

SummaryService.java:

@Service
public class SummaryService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    
    @Value("${timezone.default}")
    private String defaultSystemTimezone;
    
    public Boolean getBookingRejections() {
            Calendar calendarFirstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(defaultSystemTimezone), Locale.US);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
application.properties:

    timezone.default=America/Cambridge_Bay
```

getting below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TimeZone.parseCustomTimeZone(TimeZone.java:783)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:562)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:516)
    at com.booking.service.SummaryServiceTest.getBookingRejections(SummayServiceTest.java:)
```

not able to exact problem even TimeZone is mocked. here trying to get calendar object.

Comment: - First, better to design your code to be **TESTABLE**, means you won't need PowerMockito. Avoid PowerMockito will help your code cleaner, better design... Second, read this and make sure you didn't miss anything: https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock. Last, NPE is the easiest problem. Just put a breakpoint where it caused the NPE, and see what is being null.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the full exception message including the stack trace you get, when you run the junit test.

Comment: Why do you use `eq()` and not the direct value `"America/Cambridge_Bay"`?

Comment: to check default string value. if not using then giving below exception.org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the problem by adding setter for defaultSystemTimezone variable of SummaryService.
and set the value of var in test method.

```
SummaryService.java:

@Service
public class SummaryService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    
    @Setter
    @Value("${timezone.default}")
    private String defaultSystemTimezone;
    
    public Boolean getBookingRejections() {
            Calendar calendarFirstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(defaultSystemTimezone), Locale.US);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Test
        public void getBookingRejections() throws Exception {
            summaryService.setDefaultSystemTimezone("America/Cambridge_Bay");
            //execute test
        }
```